How to add a single backend listener to multiple Jmeter scripts/files
I have a suite of Jmeter scripts that get executed using taurus. Until now we were using Blazemeter, now shifting to Influx DB & Grafana. Now, instead of adding backend listeners to all the individual jmeter scripts, is there a way to add a single backend listener through which data from all the scripts get fed to InfluxDB?
